# Open the url inside the application when tapped on the notification - Onesignal,Phonegap

Tags: javascript, json, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, onesignal

I need to be opened the url sent by the notification inside my application. For now when I click on the notification the url is opened in my browser. Somebody please help me. Please comment if you need more details.

Answer (score 2):

Here's is the OneSignal guide on how to open a URL in your app instead of in the device's browser: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/links

> The Launch URL feature on the dashboard or the url field on the REST
>   API automatically opens the web browser on the mobile device when the
>   notification is tapped on. If you would like to open the URL inside
>   your app instead set Addition Data with a key of your choice. Example
>   targetUrl for the key and https://google.com as the value. Then in
>   your app's code read the targetUrl value from additionalData in the
>   NotificationOpened callback (name depends on the OneSignal SDK used).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create two types of messages, one to send to browsers and another one to the apps.
This question has one example of how this can be done:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/variable-launchurl/